# SELECTED VALUE & AND condition

Tags: powerbi

is it possible to use SELECTEDVALUE and AND condition in one measurement?
I have performance (in %) based on region, each region have goal. For example:

ASIA : 80 %
EU : 85%
US : 90%

I have Card visual that connect to filter to show each region performance and overall performance. But I want to give colour if I select 'ASIA' and performance is 70% the colour should be in red or if the performance is 83% the colour should be in green. Same with other regions.

Thanks!

I have tried some formulas but it's not working.